# Google Motion Chart automatically play when load the browser for some seconds?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I've been working with **Google Chart APIs** in javascript. I was wondering if **google motion chart** can automatically play when the browser gets loaded for some seconds, let's say 5 seconds or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but the Motion Chart API doesn't currently support programmatically controlling the animation. We're looking at adding this in future API versions, so please stay tuned.